# Am I using aiohttp together with psycopg2 correctly?

Tags: python, psycopg2, aiohttp

I'm very new to using asyncio/aiohttp, but I have a Python script that read a batch of URL:s from a Postgres table, downloads the URL:s, runs a processing function on each download (not relevant for the question), and saves back the result of the processing to the table.

In simplified form it looks like this:

```
import asyncio
import psycopg2
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector

BATCH_SIZE = 100

def _get_pgconn():
    return psycopg2.connect()

def db_conn(func):
    def _db_conn(*args, **kwargs):
        with _get_pgconn() as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                return func(cur, *args, **kwargs)
            conn.commit()
    return _db_conn

async def run():
    async with ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(ssl=False, limit=100)) as session:
        while True:
            count = await run_batch(session)
            if count == 0:
                break

async def run_batch(session):
    tasks = []
    for url in get_batch():
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(process_url(url, session))
        tasks.append(task)

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    results = [task.result() for task in tasks]
    save_batch_result(results)
    return len(results)

async def process_url(url, session):
    try:
        async with session.get(url, timeout=15) as response:
            body = await response.read()
            return process_body(body)
    except:
        return {...}

@db_conn
def get_batch(cur):
    sql = "SELECT id, url FROM db.urls WHERE processed IS NULL LIMIT %s"
    cur.execute(sql, (BATCH_SIZE,))
    return cur.fetchall()


@db_conn
def save_batch_result(cur, results):
    sql = "UPDATE db.urls SET a = %(a)s, processed = true WHERE id = %(id)s"
    cur.executemany(sql, tuple(results))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

But I have the feeling that I must be missing something here. The script runs but it seems to become slower and slower with each batch. Specially it seems like the call to the `process_url` function becomes slower over time. Also the used memory keeps growing so I'm guessing there might be something that I fail to clean up properly between runs?

I also have problems increasing the batch size much, if I go much over 200 I seem to get a much higher proportion of exceptions from the call to `session.get`. I have tried playing with the `limit` argument to the TCPConnector, setting it both higher and lower but I can't see that it helps much. Have also tried running it on a few different server but it seems to be the same. Is there some way to think about how to set these values more effectively?

Would be grateful for some pointers to what I might do wrong here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of your code is mixing asynchronous *aiohttp* library with **synchronous** *psycopg2* client.

As a consequence calls to DB blocks the event loop entirely affecting all other parallel tasks.

To solve it you need to use asynchronous DB client: [aiopg](https://pypi.org/project/aiopg/) (a wrapper around *psycopg2* async mode) or [asyncpg](https://pypi.org/project/asyncpg/) (it has a different API but works faster).